# Отключение изображений в WebView

Tags: java, android, android-webview

Здравствуйте. Я разрабатываю браузер который использует **webview** для отображения контента. Мне понадобилось сделать функцию отключения показа изображений, так чтобы вместо них были ссылки (если все же хочешь посмотреть изображение) как реализовать отключение, максимально безболезненно для моего кода? Или хотя бы вообще реализовать.

```
public class WebFragment extends PageFragment {
 /*Другой нужный код*/

      @Override
        public void onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu, android.view.MenuInflater inflater) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();//получение id
        if (id == R.id.cache_mode) {//id из main.xml
            showCacheDialog();//показ соответствующего диалога
            return true;
        }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);//действия при выборе пункта меню
   }


 protected void showCacheDialog() {//показываю диалог
        new MaterialDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .title("Настройки кэша")
                .items(new String[]{"Кэш и сеть", "Только сеть", "Только кэш"})
                .itemsCallbackSingleChoice(AppPreferences.getCacheMode() - 1, new MaterialDialog.ListCallbackSingleChoice() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onSelection(MaterialDialog materialDialog, View view, int i, CharSequence charSequence) {//обработка клика
                        AppPreferences.setCacheMode(i + 1);
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
}
```

Вот так выглядит реализация одной функции (кэширование).
Мне нужно что-то подобное, но с отключением изображений. (Всегда, только wi-fi, никогда)
Если нужен код, вот ссылка: [ссылка на гитхаб](http://github.com/RadiationX/WebDevBrowser)
Покажите пожалуйста пример кода, или ссылку где об этом можно почитать подробно. Спасибо ОГРОМНОЕ!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо в HTML коде, отображаемом с помощью `WebView` заменить все теги `IMG` на `A` и переименовать их аттрибуты `scr` на `href`.

Сделать это можно либо регулярками (можно, но не нужно - не делайте так) либо библиотекой для парсинга HTML. Например JSOUP.

Нужный для корректировки HTML код по URL вы можете тем же JSOUP-ом загрузить. А потом уже отобразить в `WebView` итоговый контент.

Но могут возникнуть проблемы со всякими там кнопочками и JS скриптами.